# SQLite ORDER BY timestamp does not give expected results

Tags: sqlite, datetime, timestamp, sql-order-by

I have small difficulties by sorting a `timestamp` in SQLite and I tried everything and I am still not able to get correct result.

I have a timestamp and I try to ORDER it so the most recent will be the first.

I already tried following codes:

```
db.each("SELECT values ORDER BY datetime(timestamp) DESC LIMIT 200");
db.each("SELECT values ORDER BY datetime('timestamp') DESC LIMIT 200");
db.each("SELECT values ORDER BY datetime("timestamp") DESC LIMIT 200");
db.each("SELECT values ORDER BY date(timestamp) DESC LIMIT 200");
db.each("SELECT values ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 200");
```

The last option gives me somewhat closest results unfortunately it sorts timestamps just by time, for instance rows created 17th November will be sorted correctly and rows created 18th November will be "older".

Please see following screen:

[image]

My `timestamp` format looks like this:

```
Thu Nov 17 2016 11:47:56
```

This should be very trivial, even that I did not figure out what is wrong.

**EDIT:**

Function where I generate `timestamps` looks as follows:

```
var timestamp = new Date().toString().replace(' GMT+0100 (CET)', '');
```

Comment: `unfortunately it does not take a date only times.` ... please elaborate on this, how does it work?

Comment: So I edited my question I hope now its better to understand

Comment: Store the timestamp as milliseconds since epoch and then you will always be able to sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string `'Thu Nov 17 2016 11:47:56'` is not a valid datetime string. In many countries `'Thu'` and `'Nov'` don't even have a meaning. So by

```
db.each("SELECT values ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 200");
```

you are sorting strings. `'Thu'` comes after `'Fri'`, because `'T'` comes after `'F'` in the aplhabet, so you get Thursday before Friday when sorting your data descending.

Use a valid SQLite datetime format to store your data, e.g. `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS'`. Then you can sort easily with `ORDER BY timestamp DESC`.

Comment: Or, better yet, store ms since epoch, and when a text version of the timestamp be necessary then use a function to generate it.